# Why does shell=True work when piping commands together?

Tags: python, io, subprocess, io-redirection

I have a couple `subprocess` instances I'd like to string together into a pipeline, but I am stuck and would like to ask for advice.

For example, to mimic:

```
cat data | foo - | bar - > result
```

Or:

```
foo - < data | bar - > result
```

...I first tried the following, which hangs:

```
import subprocess, sys

firstProcess = subprocess.Popen(['foo', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
secondProcess = subprocess.Popen(['bar', '-'], stdin=firstProcess.stdout,
                                 stdout=sys.stdout)

for line in sys.stdin:
    firstProcess.stdin.write(line)
    firstProcess.stdin.flush()

firstProcess.stdin.close()
firstProcess.wait()
```

My second attempt uses one `subprocess` instance with the `shell=True` parameter, which works:

```
import subprocess, sys

pipedProcess = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(['foo', '-', '|', 'bar', '-']),
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

for line in sys.stdin:
    pipedProcess.stdin.write(line)
    pipedProcess.stdin.flush()

pipedProcess.stdin.close()
pipedProcess.wait()
```

What am I doing wrong with the first, chained `subprocess` approach? I read that it is best not to use `shell=True` and I'm curious what I'm doing wrong with the first approach. Thanks for your advice.

**EDIT**

I fixed a typo in my question and fixed the `stdin` parameter of `secondProcess`. It still hangs.

I also tried removing `firstProcess.wait()` which resolves the hang, but then I get a 0-byte file as `result`.

I'll stick with the `pipedProcess`, since it works fine. But if anyone knows why the first setup hangs or makes a 0-byte file as output, I'd be interested to know why as well.

Comment: Shouldn't the stdin for `bar` be the stdout of `foo` rather than its stdin?

Comment: It should: I had a typo. I have fixed it in my question.

Comment: If you're only copying your stdin to the child's stdin then `firstProcess = Popen(['foo', '-'], stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=PIPE)` works.

Answer (score 2):

`shell=True` works because you're asking the shell to interpret your entire command line and handle the piping itself.  It is effectively as if you typed `foo - | bar -` directly into the shell.

(This is also why it can be unsafe to use `shell=True`; there are many ways to fool the shell into doing bad things that won't happen if you directly pass the command and arguments in as a list that isn't subject to parsing by any intermediaries.)

Comment: I think I added a typo and meant to have it the way you have it. And indeed I checked and that's the case. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha.  I removed the code as it is now superfluous.  I should add that it worked for me with some basic standins for `foo` and `bar` though (`sort` and `uniq`, actually), reading some random text on `stdin`.  (On further thought, that's probably because `uniq` wouldn't exit before `sort`…)

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first example, add `foo_process.stdout.close()` as [the docs suggest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline). The following code emulates `foo - | bar -` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

foo_process = Popen(['foo', '-'], stdout=PIPE)
bar_process = Popen(['bar', '-'], stdin=foo_process.stdout)
foo_process.stdout.close() # allow foo to know if bar ends
bar_process.communicate()  # equivalent to bar_process.wait() in this case
```

You don't need to use `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` explicitly here unless their different from `sys.__stdin__`, `sys.__stdout__`.

To emulate `foo - < data | bar - > result` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('data','rb') as input_file, open('result', 'wb') as output_file:
    foo = Popen(['foo', '-'], stdin=input_file, stdout=PIPE)
    bar = Popen(['bar', '-'], stdin=foo.stdout, stdout=output_file)
    foo.stdout.close() # allow foo to know if bar ends
bar.wait()
```

If you want to feed modified input line-by-line to the `foo` process i.e., to emulate `python modify_input.py | foo - | bar -` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

foo_process = Popen(['foo', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
bar_process = Popen(['bar', '-'], stdin=foo_process.stdout)
foo_process.stdout.close() # allow foo to know if bar ends
for line in sys.stdin:
    print >>foo_process.stdin, "PY", line, # modify input, feed it to `foo`
foo_process.stdin.close() # tell foo there is no more input
bar_process.wait()
```

Comment: Why would I use `bar_process.communicate()`? Wouldn't I write data to `foo_process`?

Comment: `communicate()` would likely be standing in for `wait()`, since `bar_process` will never provide output to Python.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: the code emulates your 1st example (there is no need to first read from stdin, only to write it immediately to `foo`. `foo` process can read from stdin by itself).

Comment: @AlexReynolds: `bar_process.stdin is None` so indeed `bar_process.communicate()` is just `bar_process.wait()` in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I need to process data one line at a time, in any case, and also be able to handle file handles other than `stdin`. It doesn't look like `for line in sys.stdin: ...  bar_process.communicate(line)` works.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: The code in my answer does work. It emulates `foo - | bar -`. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15374146/edit) to include the real example of what you want to do. I've updated the answer to show how to feed input line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks, but your first code snippet still does not work. I had already updated my question to fix the typo — what's there is what I want to do (eventually replacing `for line in sys.stdin:` with `for line in some_file_handle:`, which could be `sys.stdin` or a handle to a file read off of disk). I'll try out your new code snippets to see if those work.